# Core Data Relationship Does not Return Expected Instance

Tags: core-data

I have two NSManagedObjects, ListInstance and Item, and ListInstance has a one to many relationship with Item. When I ask an instance of ListInstance for its itemInstances, it tells me it's going to give me an Item at one memory address, but then it gives me an Item at a different memory address. This causes problems for me down the line, because when I update values of item.listInstance it doesn't point to the original ListInstance. Thus my original ListInstance never gets updated.

The following lldb log shows where things go wrong:

```
(lldb) po instance.itemInstances
Relationship 'itemInstances' on managed object (0x7edec030) <ListInstance: 0x7edec030> (entity: ListInstance; id: 0x7edf55f0 <x-coredata:///ListInstance/tC5D79701-0A02-4976-B8B2-DF7DDC36442C4> ; data: {
    // properties omitted   
    itemInstances =     (
        "0x7ea0af20 <x-coredata:///Item/tC5D79701-0A02-4976-B8B2-DF7DDC36442C5>"
    );
    // properties omitted   
}) with objects {(
    <Item: 0x7ea0aee0> (entity: Item; id: 0x7ea0af20 <x-coredata:///Item/tC5D79701-0A02-4976-B8B2-DF7DDC36442C5> ; data: {
    // properties omitted   
    listInstance = "0x7edf55f0 <x-coredata:///ListInstance/tC5D79701-0A02-4976-B8B2-DF7DDC36442C4>";
    listInstanceId = <ecc075981a324305b0aa9207baeb1aeb>;
    // properties omitted   
})
)}
```

Notice that "instance" thinks it points at an Item with memory address 0x7ea0af20, but when I actually ask it for the value, it returns an Item with memory address 0x7ea0aee0. Core data  thinks that both of these objects exist at x-coredata:///Item/tC5D79701-0A02-4976-B8B2-DF7DDC36442C5

Comment: Code would help. Possibly something to do with how you instantiate local properties?

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lie elsewhere. You would have to show the corresponding code.

Note that `0x7ea0af20` is the managed object ID, not the address of the `Item` object. The address of the `Item` object only occurs once and is `0x7ea0aee0` while the ID is mentioned also in the log of the relationship.

Similarly, `listInstance` has ID `0x7edf55f0` and address `0x7edec030`.